# Make my R code run faster (nested loops)

Tags: r, performance, runtime

Imagine you have a 150 by 5 matrix. Each element contains a random integer from 0 to 20.

Now think each column of the matrix as independent; I need to loop through all the possible combination of all 5 columns, which yields 150^5 = 75937500000 combinations.

It is critical I run every single combination exactly once. The order which I ran combinations do not matter.

I tried doing this using while loops. See code below.

To run this loop, based on my calculation it would take me 54 hours on my laptop.

Questions

- Any way to make my code run faster on my laptop? (bootstrapping?)
- If not, are there any web R servers I can access that would run my code at a significant faster rate?
- If not, would it make any significant difference to run this in another/faster language? (Python)

  ```
  while(counter1 <= 150)
   {
     while(counter2 <= 150)
    {
      while(counter3 <= 150)
       {
        while(counter4 <= 150)
         {
          while(counter5 <= 150)
         {
        #Other operations that take additional time#
        result<-c(
        giant_matrix[counter1,1], 
        giant_matrix[counter2,2], 
        giant_matrix[counter3,3], 
        giant_matrix[counter4,4], 
        giant_matrix[counter5,5])

        counter5=counter5+1
      }
      counter5=1
      counter4=counter4+1
    }
    counter4=1
    counter3=counter3+1
  }
  counter3=1
  counter2=counter2+1
  }
  counter2=1
  counter1=counter1+1
  }
  ```

Comment: You can try `expand.grid(m[, 1], m[, 2], m[, 3], m[, 4], m[, 5])` where `m` is the matrix in question. Does your machine have the memory to fit that large of an object?

Comment: Do you really need to store all combinations simultaneously in memory? That would require `(75,937,500,000 combo)*(5 int/combo)*(4 byte/int) = 1,518,750,000,000 byte = 1.51875 TB` of memory. I don't know of any laptops that come with that much RAM.

Comment: do you really need to run over all combinations of 150 rows? as you mentioned, numbers inside matrix are from 0 to 20, so there will be 21^5 unique combinations of data. for example, if matrix starts with rows `[1] 10 11  5 17  3` and `[2]  1  7 14 20  3` indexing combinations `c(1,1,1,1,1)` and `c(1,1,1,1,2)` will give the same resulting vectors

Answer (score 0):

Here is the above solution with a 20 x 5 matrix of 100 elements. It results in a data frame of 3,200,000 x 5 size:

```
m <- matrix(sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 20)
df <- expand.grid(m[, 1], m[, 2], m[, 3], m[, 4], m[, 5])
```

Example output of the above df (head):

```
head(df)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
1   10   19   13    4    7
2   19   19   13    4    7
3    3   19   13    4    7
4    5   19   13    4    7
5   11   19   13    4    7
6    8   19   13    4    7

nrow(df)
[1] 3200000

dim(df)
[1] 3200000       5
```